# 2D array indeces question

Tags: c#, arrays

I am quite confused, if I create array [5,10] then it means it has 5 rows and 10 columns? So its Y,X, right?
Confusing to me as I am used to work with X,Y order.

Comment: take a look of this link, will help you getting the point clear :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well, row, column, X, Y, that's all up to interpretation isn't it?

[5,10] creates an array that contains 5 items.  Each item is a 10 member array.

[10,5] creates an array that contains 10 items.  Each item is a 5 member array.

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: According to MSDN it's exactly 5 rows and 10 columns no matter how you interpret that.

Comment: That might be the language they use, but if I so choose I could totally represent a 10 row/5 column matrix using [5,10].  It's all about how you interpret the values.  Especially, if I cared more about iterating through the rows more than the columns, because that operation is faster with [5,10] than [10,5]

Comment: A small correction: A two dimensional array is a single array with two dimensions, it's not an array of arrays. [5,10] creates a single array with 50 items.

Comment: @Guffa: Really? Is that language-dependent? I've always understood any type of multidimensional array as being an array of arrays. Are you saying that it's more accurate to think of jagged arrays as being "arrays of arrays," but not multidimensional?

Comment: @Cody Gray: It's language dependent in the way that some languages (like Javascript) doesn't have multi dimensional arrays, and in some languages (like C) the array notation is just adding an offset to a pointer. A multi dimensional array is a single object and only have to be created once, while a jagged array is an array of arrays where each sub-array has to be created and added to the main array.

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually creating with the above syntax is called a "[multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=VS.100).aspx)", or an *array of arrays*. Specifically, you're creating an array that contains 5 items, and each of those 5 items itself contains 10 items.

A single dimensional array can be seen as a single row of elements:

[image: Single dimensional array]

A bidimensional array (the most common case of multidimensional array) can therefore be seen as simply adding another row of elements, producing the table visualization that you're familiar with:

[image: Bi-dimensional array]

However, you can mentally construct that table however you wish. If you're more comfortable with the `(X, Y)` syntax, use that instead.

Remember though, that multidimensional arrays are not limited to only two indices. That makes them more difficult to conceptualize as a table as you increase the number of indices.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are processing a huge array in a tight loop (so that memory caching is affected), how you interpret the dimensions in an array doesn't matter.

There is no special case for a two dimensional array that forces you to use [y,x] rather than [x,y]. Consider that a one dimensional array can represent a row, a column, or something completely different. A three dimensional array doesn't have to represent the three spacial dimensions.

I believe that the more intuitive way of using the indices for most users when a two dimensional array represents a grid, is [x,y].